# Specflow - Scenario outline doesn't generate steps for examples

Tags: nunit, bdd, specflow

I'm trying to use scenario outline in Specflow, but the Steps generator doesn't generate steps for all examples, but generate stpets only for first example.

I'm using portuguese language.

That's my scenario outline

```
Esquema do Cenário: CN[02] Um campo obrigatório não está preenchido
    Dado que eu não preenchi o campo <NomeCampo>
    Quando eu clicar no botão Salvar
    Então o sistema deve informar que o preenchimento do campo <NomeCampo> é obrigatório
```

That's my examples:

```
Exemplos:
| NomeCampo     |
| Nome Completo |
| E-mail        |
```

When I try generate steps definitions file, the framework generate steps only for "Nome Completo" example. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you should show the generated steps, it'll help if there actually are problems but I think this is expected behaviour

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behaviour. The steps are the same, so should be reused by the scenario outlines.

When you use a scenario outline you effectively are specifying two scenarios which are the same, but with different data, and the differences are encapsulated in the parameters of the steps. So you should expect only one method for each step to be generated. Specflow will manage the calling of the steps with the different data in the examples when it runs the scenario.